# Return the list of dimnames of 3D array by selecting specific elements in r

Tags: r, arrays

When I have a 3D array, I want to obtain the list of row names and column names when selecting some elements in array.
For example,

```
mdat <- array(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6), dim= c(2, 3, 2),dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3"),c("m1","m2")))
```

`which(mdat[,,2]==2)` returns location of the elements but I want to obtain the paired row names and column names which are (row 2,c.1),(row 2,c.2). I haven't found a way to get the dimname in 3D array. Have anyone tried this??  Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
tmp <- mdat[,,2]
mat <- which(tmp==2, arr.ind = TRUE)
cbind(rownames(tmp)[mat[, 1]], colnames(tmp)[mat[, 2]])
#      [,1]   [,2] 
#[1,] "row2" "C.1"
#[2,] "row2" "C.2"
```

Comment: Thanks and I will try it! Both of answers help lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below with `which` + `dimnames` like below

```
inds <- which(mdat[,,2]==2,arr.ind = T)
nm <- dimnames(mdat[,,2])
sapply(seq_along(nm),function(k) nm[[k]][inds[,k]])
```

which gives

```
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,] "row2" "C.1"
[2,] "row2" "C.2"
```

Comment: Thanks and I will try it!